# How can I fix the following error, 'RenderBuffer' does not contain a definition for 'velocity', in unity c#?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a simple player movement script, but I am running into the following error 'RenderBuffer' does not contain a definition for 'velocity', and I don't know how to fix it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting.Antlr3.Runtime.Tree;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour

{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private BoxCollider2D coll;

    private bool hasDoubleJumped = false;

    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed = 7f;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForce = 14f;

    [SerializeField] private LayerMask jumpableGround;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        coll = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float dirX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded())
        {
            hasDoubleJumped = false;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(RenderBuffer.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        }

        else if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && !hasDoubleJumped)
        {
            hasDoubleJumped = true;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(RenderBuffer.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        }
    }

    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        return Physics2D.BoxCast(coll.bounds.center, coll.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.down, .1f, jumpableGround);
    }
}
```

I have tried changing a few things, but it doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

On your jump logic you wrote `RenderBuffer.velocity.x`, seems out of place, try `rb.velocity.x` if you want to to access the current rigidbody velocity.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is with the code `RenderBuffer.velocity` which is trying to access the velocity property of [RenderBuffer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderBuffer.html), but velocity isn't a property of RenderBuffer.  I notice you also have code like `rb.veclocity` where rb refers to a [RigidBody](https://https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) (which does have a velocity property).  Could you have a typo here?  Perhaps you just need to replace `RigidBody.velocity` with `rb.velocity` in your code.